# Having trouble getting Array values to write to memory

Tags: c, arrays, arduino

I'm using an arduino with an adafruit FRAM memory breakout.  I'm trying to get the following to extract values from an array, and then save those to the FRAM.  The problem is the values being saved aren't the right ones.  What conversion needs to happen to make these values store?

```
#include <Wire.h>        
#include "Adafruit_FRAM_I2C.h"        
String incomingData = "244,1,1,7,13,1,0";        


Adafruit_FRAM_I2C fram     = Adafruit_FRAM_I2C();        
uint16_t          framAddr = 0;        
void setup(void) {        

 Serial.begin(9600);        

  if (fram.begin()) {  // you can stick the new i2c addr in here, e.g. begin(0x51);        
    Serial.println("Found I2C FRAM");        
  } else {        
    Serial.println("I2C FRAM not identified \r\n");          
  }        

uint8_t input[16];        

incomingData.getBytes(input,16);        
uint8_t *str;        
int i_ctr;        
uint8_t arr[16][16];            

for(i_ctr = 0,str = strtok(input,","); str!= NULL; i_ctr++, str= strtok(NULL,","))        
  {        
    strcpy( arr[i_ctr], str);        
  }        


fram.write8(0x0, arr[0]);        
               fram.write8(0x1,  arr[1]);        
              fram.write8(0x2, arr[2]);        
fram.write8(0x3, arr[3]);        
               fram.write8(0x4, arr[4]);        
               fram.write8(0x5, arr[5]);        
               fram.write8(0x6, arr[6]);        
               fram.write8(0x7, 77); //test        

  Serial.println(fram.read8(0x0));        
  Serial.println(fram.read8(0x1));        
  Serial.println(fram.read8(0x2));        
  Serial.println(fram.read8(0x3));        
  Serial.println(fram.read8(0x4));        
  Serial.println(fram.read8(0x5));        
  Serial.println(fram.read8(0x6));        
    Serial.println(fram.read8(0x7));        

}
```

This outputs:

```
218
234
250
10
26
42
58
77
```

Answer (score 0):

`arr[i]` is an address, and what you actually writing are the low byte of the addresses (see how the printed values are 16 apart). If you want to have numerical values of incoming data, change your code to

```
    uint8_t arr[16];  // One dimension is enough
    for (....) {
        arr[i_ctr] = atoi(str);
    }
```

PS: haven't you get any compiler warning?

Comment: Thanks!  That did it.